# How do I correct Angular errors on binding to properties

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm getting the below errors and have been unable to find a solution. I'm using Angular version 9. I get this error messages in the form template. I'm building it with `ReactiveFormsModule`.

> error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form' 
> error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'em'

the class component

```typescript
    import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { TOASTR_TOKEN, Toastr } from '../commons/toastr.service';
    
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-contact',
      templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
    })
    export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
      contactForm: FormGroup;
      nameMessage: string;
      mouseoverLogin: boolean = false;
    
      private validationMessages = {
        required: 'This field is required',
        email: 'Must be a valid email',
        pattern: 'Name must not start with a number'
      }
      constructor(private router: Router,
                  @Inject(TOASTR_TOKEN) private toastr: Toastr) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.contactForm = new FormGroup({
          firstName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z].*')]),
          lastName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z].*')]),
          email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
          message: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(50)])
        });
    
        this.firstName.valueChanges.pipe(
          debounceTime(1000)
        ).subscribe(value => {
          this.setMessage(this.firstName);
        });
    
        this.lastName.valueChanges.pipe(
          debounceTime(1000)
        ).subscribe(value => {
          this.setMessage(this.lastName);
        });
    
        this.email.valueChanges.pipe(
          debounceTime(1000)
        ).subscribe(value => {
          this.setMessage(this.email);
        });
    
        this.message.valueChanges.pipe(
          debounceTime(1000)
        ).subscribe(value => {
          this.setMessage(this.message);
        });
      }
    
      get firstName() {
        return this.contactForm.get('firstName');
      }
      get lastName() {
        return this.contactForm.get('lastName');
      }
      get email() {
        return this.contactForm.get('email');
      }
      get message() {
        return this.contactForm.get('message');
      }
    
      setMessage(c: AbstractControl): void {
        this.nameMessage = '';
        if((c.touched || c.dirty) && c.errors) {
          this.nameMessage = Object.keys(c.errors).map(
            key => this.validationMessages[key]).join(' ');
        }
      }
    
      cancel() {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }
    
      sendMessage(formValues: any) {
        if(this.contactForm.valid) {
          this.toastr.success('Message Sent');
          console.log(formValues)
        }
      }
    
      get validateFirstName() {
        return this.contactForm.controls.firstName.invalid && this.contactForm.controls.firstName.touched
      }
    
      get validateLastName() {
        return this.contactForm.controls.lastName.invalid && this.contactForm.controls.lastName.touched
      }
      get validateEmail() {
        return this.contactForm.controls.email.invalid && this.contactForm.controls.email.touched
      }
      get validateMessage() {
        return this.contactForm.controls.message.invalid && this.contactForm.controls.message.touched
      }
    }
```

the html

```html
    <div class="container" [style.color]="'white'">
      <div style="padding-top: 3rem; padding-bottom: 1rem;">
        <h1>Send me a message</h1>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <form [formGroup]="contactForm" autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="sendMessage(contactForm.value)">
          <div class="form-group" [class.error]="validateFirstName">
            <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
            <em *ngIf="firstName?.invalid && (firstName?.touched || mouseoverLogin)">{{ nameMessage }}</em>
            <input formControlName="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="First Name..." />
          </div>
          <span (mouseenter)="mouseoverLogin=true" (mouseleave)="mouseoverLogin=false">
            <button [disabled]="contactForm.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
          </span>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

The module where i declared the ContactCompont


    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { VisitorRoutingModule } from './visitor-routing.module';

    import { ContactComponent } from './contact.component';


    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        VisitorRoutingModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        ContactComponent
      ],
      providers: []
    })
    export class VisitorModule { }
```

Comment: did you import the ReactiveModule and CommonModule in your app Module ?

Comment: Yes I did. Both of them

Comment: can you share your code please,

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com

Comment: thanks i found a way around the issue

Comment: can you share the module you have declared `ContactComponent`